# Converting Javascript Multidimensional Array format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this -

```
var myOldArray = [{
        "id": 1,
        "form_id": 4,
        "form_field_name": "field_1",
        "helperTitle": "This is Box 1's TItle",
        "helperText": "This is Box 1 data",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "form_id": 4,
        "form_field_name": "field_2",
        "helperTitle": "Box 2 Title",
        "helperText": "Box 2 TExt",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
    }
]
```

and I need to duplicate / copy / convert / ...whatever... that array to something like this -

```
myNewArray = {
  field_1['title'] = "This is Box 1's Title",
  field_1['text'] = "This is Box 1 data",
  field_2['title'] = "Box 2 Title",
  field_2['text'] = "Box 2 Text",
}
```

so that I can reference it by

```
  console.log(myNewArray.field_1.title)
```

or something more usable.

I have attempted to use the filter method to no avail. Everything I've attempted just returns undefined. I'm just super confused. Is there a better way to reference the elements in the sub array directly without converting?

This was sorta working... the console.log would output what I wanted but the returned value would output as undefined, which is confusing me.

```js
myOldArray = [{
    "id": 1,
    "form_id": 4,
    "form_field_name": "field_1",
    "helperTitle": "This is Box 1's TItle",
    "helperText": "This is Box 1 data",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "form_id": 4,
    "form_field_name": "field_2",
    "helperTitle": "Box 2 Title",
    "helperText": "Box 2 TExt",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  }
]
var AR = myOldArray;
var newArr = AR.filter(function(item) {
  if (item.form_field_name == fieldName) {
    console.log('txt - ' + item + '\n\n');
    return item;
  }
});
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: btw, your `myNewArray` should be an object instead of an array, because you use named properties instead of keys.

Comment: Yeah, I thought I'd used curly braces on the myNewArray, but I've been trying to solve this thing for like 6 hours... tiredness has kicked in... I fixed it.

Comment: What's wrong (or not usable) with `myOldArray[0].helperTitle`?

Comment: I dont know which array index I need when I output it.

I need to reference specific indexes - IE, I need to output helperTitle for the index where form_field_name = field_2 and I wont know if that's index 0 or 1, or there may be 100 items in that array.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made for you with relevant HTML

Comment: @Deadlance Sounds like you really need to learn about data structures in JS a bit more..

Comment: @Ben I am working on learning as much as I can as quickly as I can for sure. This is just a weird issue I've been stuck on. I can't figure out how to get specific indexes of multidimensional arrays via key / value pair instead of their index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could map the items in new objects with the wanted properties as objects.

It works with

- mapping the objects of the array with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),
- taking the relevant properties with a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and make some renaming with [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern),
- return a new object with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) `field` with another object with the renamed properties,
- assigns all new objects to a single object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, form_id: 4, form_field_name: "field_1", helperTitle: "This is Box 1's TItle", helperText: "This is Box 1 data", created_at: null, updated_at: null }, { id: 2, form_id: 4, form_field_name: "field_2", helperTitle: "Box 2 Title", helperText: "Box 2 TExt", created_at: null, updated_at: null }],
    result = Object.assign(
        ...data.map(({ id, helperTitle: title, helperText: text }) =>
            ({ ['field_' + id]: { title, text } }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm having issues posting code in comments apparently... but I'm getting an error with the code you provided that says

Can't convert undefined to object.

Comment: $.get('/api/system/formHelperText/4', function(data) {
                      if(data) {
                          this.helpText = data;
                      }
                  }.bind(this));
                    var X = this.helpText;
                    console.log(X);
                    result = Object.assign(
                        ...X.map(({ id, helperTitle: title, helperText: text }) =>
                            ({ ['field_' + id]: { title, text } }))
                    );
                    console.log(result);

Comment: it looks like an async problem, because of the `undefined` do you see the array in the console.log? can you take an item of the array?

Comment: @Deadlance don't you need to parse the JSON string to object

Comment: in my poorly formatted above code, the first console.log(X) does indeed output the array into the log, but the console.log(result) is producing the error

Comment: @Slai I don't think so. console.log(this.helpText[0].helperTitle); is outputting the proper string. The issue I'm having is, I don't want to output the string from [0]... I need to get the string for the index where form_field_name = a specific thing.

Comment: as i wrote, it could be an async propblem, where you process data which is not available at this moment.

Comment: @ninaScholz it does appear to be an async problem... Now to figure out how to fix that issue...

Comment: @deadlance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing all of the processing should be in the $.get function :

```
$.getJSON('/api/system/formHelperText/4', function (data) { 
    var myNewArray = data.map(function(item) {
        var obj = {};
        obj['field_' + item.id] = { Title: item.helperTitle, Text: item.helperText };
        return obj;
    });
    console.log(myNewArray);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call to get the desired output:

```js
const array=[{id:1,form_id:4,form_field_name:"field_1",helperTitle:"This is Box 1's TItle",helperText:"This is Box 1 data",created_at:null,updated_at:null},{id:2,form_id:4,form_field_name:"field_2",helperTitle:"Box 2 Title",helperText:"Box 2 TExt",created_at:null,updated_at:null}]

const result= array.reduce((acc, a) => 
  (acc[a.form_field_name] = {title: a.helperTitle,text: a.helperText}, acc), {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple:

```
const objs = new Map();

for (const obj of myOldArray) {
    objs.set(obj.form_field_name, obj);
}
```

And now you can access your objects by the field name:

```
const myObj = objs.get("field_1");
```